# Javascript designMode remove <font> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I am making a WYSIWYG editor for fun. I am using an iframe with designmode and using the execcommand feature on javascript to create my WYSIWYG editor. I use the following code to apply a font size to text in the WYSIWYG editor:

```
richTextField.document.execCommand('fontSize',false,slctdValue);
```

This changes the Iframe content to this:

```
<div><font size="4" color="red">This is a test!</font></div>
```

I do not like using the font tag I would rather replace it with the following:

```
<div style="font-size:22px;color:red;">This is a test!</div>
```

Is there a way I can find code similar to the first example and replace it with the second example?

Comment: Can you have an id for that div as slctdFontSizeValue and pass it to the execCommand?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').css({'font-size':'100%'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-size:22px;color:red;">This is a test!</div>
```

Comment: i tried this and it only edits the last div in the editor but if i have more than one div then the others are not changing, it also dosnt remove the font tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a working jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jonolayton/0851d2uk/4/

This code finds all "font" tags, and replaces them with the equivalent "div" as requested.

Here's what I did:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <font size="4" color="red">This is a test!</font>
    <font size="4" color="green">This is a test!</font>
    <font size="4" color="blue">This is a test!</font>
    <font size="4" color="pink">This is a test!</font>
    <font size="4" color="yellow">This is a test!</font>
    <font size="4" color="brown">This is a test!</font>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('font').each(function() {
        var size = $(this).attr('size');
        var color = $(this).attr('color');
        var text = $(this).text();

        $('<div></div>').insertAfter($(this)).css({
            'font-size' : '22px',
            'color' : color
        }).text(text);
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```